# Play audio sound on button click with no repeating

Tags: android, audio

I want to either be able to have a single button that you click to start and click again to stop or a start button that does not start multiple sounds each time it clicks. I have an audio file that if you click start 3 times, it has 3 different tracks going all at once. And the stop button stops only one, the other tracks keep playing until I kill the app.

Here is my code.  I am a noob

```
package com.example.mitch_000.button;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player=MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.lw);

                player.start();}

        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.stop();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are creating the MediaPlayer object every time `button1` is clicked. If you only want to have the single audio file played, then you should instantiate your MediaPlayer once in onCreate, and then your references to `player` should work.

Comment: Move `player=MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.lw);` outside of your `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `player=MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.lw);` in your `OnClickListener`, you are creating a new instance of the audio file and then playing it *every time the button is clicked*.

You need to create a single instance of the `player` object outside of the `OnClickListener` (in `OnCreate`) and then you can use this reference to play, pause and stop the one audio file.

Here is the code you can use:

```
package com.example.mitch_000.button;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    player=MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.lw);
    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.start();
        }

    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.stop();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mamacita_zero);
```

outside of `setOnClickListener`

like this

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.lw);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.stop();

        }

    });

  }

  }
```

You seem to be doing  per click than you need to. You're creating and adding a new onClickListener for every click in the Activity's View, not the Button. You only need to set the listener once, and for the Button rather than the overarching View; I tend to do that in the constructor of the Activity.

Comment: That's not an answer unless you explain *why* -- otherwise it looks like you just plagiarized a comment.

Comment: Naw, I'm not going to remove my downvote. That code up there won't work. You're defining a constructor rather than overriding the `onCreate()`. And you still don't explain your initial answer. Please don't post answers unless they are complete.

Comment: Why duplicate a correct answer? Yours isn't, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61642/discussion-between-ntk88-and-323go).